# API returned error: "Duplicate instance, please try again with different values."

Tags: ruby, coinbase-api

I'm using the Coinbase connector for Ruby, and I'm receiving a `Coinbase::Wallet::ValidationError` with the description `Duplicate instance, please try again with different values.` when doing a `Coinbase::Wallet::Account::sell` operation.
I have been trying to understand which is the error with the API documentation and along the web, but no luck.
Could you give an explanation of which is the error here?

Comment: Can you please link the library you are using? I was only able to find a deprecated one.

Comment: We are using https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-ruby, which is deprecated, we know. But while we change it, we would like to know which is the reason for the Duplicate instance, please try again with different values in the raw API, so we can map it to our system errors. But the Coinbase API documentation does not have any reference to this specific error.